# Cannot consume scoped service 'ApplicationDbContext' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ihostedservice

I'm using .Net Core Background Service to Connect to Kafka and save messages to SQL Server. My Project Structure looks like this:
[image]

In the Infrastructure Dependency, I have the following code to register `Entity Framework` using `IConfiguration configuration` passed from Worker's `Program.cs` file i.e. `services.AddInfrastructure(configuration)`;

```
namespace JS.Svf.BackgroundServices.Infrastructure
{
    public static class DependencyInjection
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            // Add all the dependencies required by Azure Functions.
            // From Infrastructure

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                       options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                           b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));

            services.AddTransient<IApplicationDbContext>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>());
            services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<ISupplierRepository, SupplierRepository>();
            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error after running the Background Service:
`Cannot consume scoped service 'ApplicationDbContext' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'`

With reference, I came to know that we need to use `IServiceScopeFactory` but I'm bit clueless about how to use it with the current structure. Please advice.

The repository uses the `ApplicationDbContext`. How to use `IServiceScopeFactory` here?

```
namespace JS.Svf.Functions.Infrastructure.Persistence
{
    public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public Repository(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your singleton service, the `IHostedService`, inject an `IServiceScopeFactory` into it and use that to create a scope and get a new `DbContext` from it. For example:

```
public class MyHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public MyHostedService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        // Inject the scope factory
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    private async Task SomeMethodThatNeedsTheContext()
    {
        // Create a new scope (since DbContext is scoped by default)
        using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();

        // Get a Dbcontext from the scope
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider
            .GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();           

        // Run a query on your context
        var quadrupeds = await context.Animals
            .Where(a => a.Legs == 4)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: EF is in another project and I'm accessing it via Repositories. I've updated the post to include my repo code as well. Please check and give some pointers on the same

Comment: There's no difference, you just need to request a  repository instead of a context from the scope.